# Play routing issue

Tags: playframework, routes, href

I am trying to resolve reverse routing in ajax call.

I have a list java objects having links say:

link 1: - abc
link 2: - def
and so on..

Which I am trying to render in a html which is loaded in an ajax call. But the output that I get on href is
abc, instead of the URL mapping of @{abc.def}

Please help..

Comment: What version of play is this? What controller function are you trying to call?

Comment: I am using play 1.2.4. Its a custom controller which extends Application and a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @routes.YourController.YourMethod() to get link